# What is the best practice about xml deserialization in ActionScript 3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, serialization, actionscript, deserialization

What is the best practice about xml deserialization in ActionScript 3?

I'm developing a real time multiplayer Facebook game. 
I prefered writing client side with Flash. Beside, server-side is written with Java. Communication between server and client is provided with "socket".
Server and client sends xml to each other. As might be expected those Xmls contains "objects" which are derived from classes located in both side.
Class names and attributes are synchronised.

Turning to the my issue, I've tried some libraries for serialization and deserialization at actionscript side. But most of them doesn't work completely.

For example;

Asx3mer.instance.fromXML(xmlObj)

This library doesn't convert xml into object which has an Array attribute and that array contains another array(I mean nested array).

Could you help me to handle this problem?

Thanks.

---

At first, I choosed json for automatic serialization. But when I deserialized the json object, it's converted to a object having class type "Object". At every turn I was obliged to put an identifier in json string in order to handle its type.

I've researched AMF, but as you've mentioned, AMF use its messaging standart, and I thought it might be hard to handle deserializing objects at server side(But now, my choice shows that client side deserialization got unwieldy).

Comment: Can't you use the native XML object?

Comment: Deserializing objects at server side is usually not difficult because there are AMF libraries for most languages and frameworks. What kind of performances do you need for your game? If performance might be an issue then AMF is probably the best choices because it's fast to derialize and serialize client-side. If performance is not so critical, you might want to go for JSON and do your own type conversion. JSON is a good choice because it is generally easier to debug than AMF.

Comment: @Laurent Server side is not so hard to handle. My problem is with client site. Performance is not important at this time. I don't have enough time to make my own type conversion code. I'm researching prepared ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want this kind of automatic object serialization, I suggest you use something with better type support. AMF, the native ActionScript serialization format could be a very good choice for your project. It is supported natively by Flash and there is a [library for Java](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Java+AMF+Client). The format is also much more compact than XML (in fact, I wonder why you chose XML for your game instead of JSON or, indeed, AMF).

Comment: +1 to this. If you don't want to go the AMF route JSON would be a better choice.

Comment: @Laurent I don't prefer AMF because the game that I developed is asynchronous. AMF doesn't allow server to send a response until client sends a request. It's clear, I have to provide "socket connection" between them. Maybe I'm wrong with choosing xml serialization. But JSON deserialization in Flash side is a hell, I mean. I've tried lots of library at JSON. Non of them couldn't convert the json string to specified type. The converted objects' types are always "OBJECT". If you know the solution, could you please share with me, with us?